# Ionic JavaScript Function works on first load but not on the second

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

In my case, I'm just executing a simple JavaScript function to a div element with `id="bodyText"`. The first time I enter to ArticlePage it works as desired.

```
export class ArticlePage implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    let bodyWrapper = document.getElementById('bodyText');
    bodyWrapper.innerHTML = "";
    bodyWrapper.classList.add('my-class')
  }
}
```

However, when I leave the page and re enter, the function does not work again. This is the HTML of stored pages.

```
<ng-component class="app-root">
  <ion-nav ng-reflect-root="function HomePage(navCtrl, n">
    <div nav-viewport=""></div>
    <page-article style="z-index: 101"></page-article> // Function works fine
    <page-other1 style="z-index: 102"></page-other1>
    <page-other2 style="z-index: 103"></page-other2>
    <page-article style="z-index: 104"><page-article> // Function doesn't work
    <div class="nav-decor"></div>
  </ion-nav>
</ng-component>
```

How can I make this function work each time I visit the same page?

Comment: Sounds like the expected behavior: `ngOnInit()` is called only when initializing the page. Unless it is destroyed and re-initialized, there is no reason for this hook to be called twice.

Consider other possible Angular hooks: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Comment: try using ionViewDidLoad() insted of ngOnInit()

Comment: I already have tried with ionViewDidLoad(), the same problem happens.